# Shopify product tab and facebook description issue

Tags: facebook, tabs, shopify, product, store

I'm newbie on shopify and Right now I'm creating a shopify store. I'm facing two issues on my shopify store.

1. I'm using the paid theme and it does not have any tabs option on product page so from long time I'm putting the content by using simple HTML code (Ul/li tags) in the description box. But now I wanted to add a proper tab section because I have a lot of products and it takes a lot time to code every time for individual products. So please suggest some plugin or way to add tab sections on the product page backend. (I've no issues in paying for plugin as well)
2. Another issue is that my facebook is automatically picking up all the content from description and tabs as my shopify store is connected to facebook and whenever I try to add products on facebook it takes the complete content from description and tabs as well. I just wanted to put product description on my facebook and do not want to add tab content. (This could be because right now I don't have separate tabs section and I'm using html code in the description section to add the tab section on my shopify store)

So I'm hoping that separating a tab and description section will resolve my both issues. but If it doesn't resolve the issue then what option option I can try to resolve the facebook issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to start with a Shopify built theme.
Then you can arrange a chat with the Shopify Theme guys, they help you with lots of additional resources to tweak the theme. The support team for Shopify is very helpful.

Also, the FB channel within your Shopify page can be tweaked to solve this issue.

Comment: I'm already using the paid theme which I bought from shopify.

Comment: Which plugin you suggest? and also please share the process of setting up that plugin please.

Comment: Hi sharing link of the app i mentioned  [link](https://apps.shopify.com/facebook-marketplace-connector) , just add the app by clicking the link, it's free!!